# How to test if after pressing a button it goes to the next window

Tags: kotlin, testing, android-jetpack-compose, android-testing

I am making an app that has a quizz with Jetpack Compose. The quizz gives you a question and 4 answers to choose from, but it also comes with a 'Next' button in case you want to skip the question. I want to make a test to check if after clicking next Question 2 appears. Note that on top of every question it says Question X, X being the number of the question you're on

This is the Quiz Screen code:

```
package com.example.myfirstapplication.quiz

import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.myfirstapplication.models.Album
import com.example.myfirstapplication.models.Question
import com.example.myfirstapplication.models.Song
import com.example.myfirstapplication.repository.Resources
import com.example.myfirstapplication.repository.StorageRepository
import com.example.myfirstapplication.repository.numberOfArtists
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class QuizViewModel(
    private val repository: StorageRepository = StorageRepository(),
    ): ViewModel() {

    var quizUiState by mutableStateOf(QuizUiState())
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // do API call
            loadQuestion()

        }
    }
    val hasUser:Boolean
        get() = repository.hasUser()
    private val userId:String
        get() = repository.getUserId()



        fun loadQuestion(){
            if(hasUser){
                if(userId.isNotBlank()){
                    getRandomQuestion()

                }
            }
        }

        private fun getRandomQuestion() {
            repository.getRandQuestion( onError = {}){
                quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(question = it)
                getQuestionSubject()
                getAnswers()
            }

        }

        fun getQuestionSubject() {
            if(quizUiState.question?.Type == "song" ){
                quizUiState.question?.let { getSongs(number = 1) }
            }
            else if (quizUiState.question?.Type == "album" ){
                quizUiState.question?.let { getAlbums(number = 1) }
            }

        }

        fun getAnswers(){
            if(quizUiState.question?.AnswerType == "song" ){
                quizUiState.question?.let { getSongs(number = 3) }
            }
            else if (quizUiState.question?.AnswerType == "album" ){
                quizUiState.question?.let { getAlbums(number = 3) }
            }
            else if (quizUiState.question?.AnswerType == "artist" ){
                quizUiState.question?.let { getArtists(number = 3) }
            }
            else if (quizUiState.question?.AnswerType == "date" ){
                quizUiState.question?.let { getDates(number = 3) }
            }
        }

        private fun getSongs(number:Int){
            repository.getSongs(number=number, onError = {}){
                if(number == 1){
                    if (it != null) {
                        quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(subject = it.get(0).name)
                        if(quizUiState.question?.AnswerType   == "album"){
                            quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(answer = it.get(0).album)
                        }
                        else if(quizUiState.question?.AnswerType   == "artist"){
                            quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(answer = it.get(0).author)
                        }
                        else if(quizUiState.question?.AnswerType   == "date"){
                            quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(answer = it.get(0).date)
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if (it != null) {
                        var answers = ArrayList<String>()
                        for(items in it){
                            answers.add(items.name)
                        }
                        answers.add(quizUiState.answer)
                        answers = answers.shuffled() as ArrayList<String>
                        quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(answerList = answers)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private fun getAlbums(number:Int){
            repository.getAlbums(number=number, onError = {}){
                if(number == 1){
                    if (it != null) {
                        quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(subject = it.get(0).name)
                        if(quizUiState.question?.AnswerType   == "artist"){
                            quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(answer = it.get(0).author)
                        }
                        else if(quizUiState.question?.AnswerType   == "date"){
                            quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(answer = it.get(0).date)
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if (it != null) {
                        var answers = ArrayList<String>()
                        for(items in it){
                            answers.add(items.name)
                        }
                        answers.add(quizUiState.answer)
                        answers = answers.shuffled() as ArrayList<String>
                        quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(answerList = answers)
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        private fun getArtists(number: Int){
            repository.getArtists(number, onError = {}){
                if(number == 1) {   //////////////////////////////////////////////LEFT TO BE DONE
                    if (it != null) {
                        quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(subject = it.get(0).name)
                    }
                }else{
                    if (it != null) {
                        var answers = ArrayList<String>()
                        for(items in it){
                            answers.add(items.name)
                        }
                        answers.add(quizUiState.answer)
                        answers = answers.shuffled() as ArrayList<String>
                        quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(answerList = answers)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private fun getDates(number: Int){
            repository.getDates(number, onError = {}){
                if(number == 1) {   //////////////////////////////////////////////LEFT TO BE DONE
                    if (it != null) {
                        quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(subject = it.get(0).date)
                    }
                }else{
                    if (it != null) {
                        var answers = ArrayList<String>()
                        for(items in it){
                            answers.add(items.date)
                        }
                        answers.add(quizUiState.answer)
                        answers = answers.shuffled() as ArrayList<String>
                        quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(answerList = answers)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fun resetUi(){
            viewModelScope.launch {
                // do API call
                quizUiState = QuizUiState()
                loadQuestion()

            }
        }



}
        // get random question -> according to type ->
        // get random song/album -> set question answer according to Answer type










data class QuizUiState(
    val answerList: List<String>? = null,
    val question: Question? = null,
    val answer: String = "",
    val subject: String = "",

)
```

This is the ViewModel:

```
package com.example.myfirstapplication.quiz

import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.myfirstapplication.models.Album
import com.example.myfirstapplication.models.Question
import com.example.myfirstapplication.models.Song
import com.example.myfirstapplication.repository.Resources
import com.example.myfirstapplication.repository.StorageRepository
import com.example.myfirstapplication.repository.numberOfArtists
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class QuizViewModel(
    private val repository: StorageRepository = StorageRepository(),
    ): ViewModel() {

    var quizUiState by mutableStateOf(QuizUiState())
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // do API call
            loadQuestion()

        }
    }
    val hasUser:Boolean
        get() = repository.hasUser()
    private val userId:String
        get() = repository.getUserId()



        fun loadQuestion(){
            if(hasUser){
                if(userId.isNotBlank()){
                    getRandomQuestion()

                }
            }
        }

        private fun getRandomQuestion() {
            repository.getRandQuestion( onError = {}){
                quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(question = it)
                getQuestionSubject()
                getAnswers()
            }

        }

        fun getQuestionSubject() {
            if(quizUiState.question?.Type == "song" ){
                quizUiState.question?.let { getSongs(number = 1) }
            }
            else if (quizUiState.question?.Type == "album" ){
                quizUiState.question?.let { getAlbums(number = 1) }
            }

        }

        fun getAnswers(){
            if(quizUiState.question?.AnswerType == "song" ){
                quizUiState.question?.let { getSongs(number = 3) }
            }
            else if (quizUiState.question?.AnswerType == "album" ){
                quizUiState.question?.let { getAlbums(number = 3) }
            }
            else if (quizUiState.question?.AnswerType == "artist" ){
                quizUiState.question?.let { getArtists(number = 3) }
            }
            else if (quizUiState.question?.AnswerType == "date" ){
                quizUiState.question?.let { getDates(number = 3) }
            }
        }

        private fun getSongs(number:Int){
            repository.getSongs(number=number, onError = {}){
                if(number == 1){
                    if (it != null) {
                        quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(subject = it.get(0).name)
                        if(quizUiState.question?.AnswerType   == "album"){
                            quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(answer = it.get(0).album)
                        }
                        else if(quizUiState.question?.AnswerType   == "artist"){
                            quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(answer = it.get(0).author)
                        }
                        else if(quizUiState.question?.AnswerType   == "date"){
                            quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(answer = it.get(0).date)
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if (it != null) {
                        var answers = ArrayList<String>()
                        for(items in it){
                            answers.add(items.name)
                        }
                        answers.add(quizUiState.answer)
                        answers = answers.shuffled() as ArrayList<String>
                        quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(answerList = answers)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private fun getAlbums(number:Int){
            repository.getAlbums(number=number, onError = {}){
                if(number == 1){
                    if (it != null) {
                        quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(subject = it.get(0).name)
                        if(quizUiState.question?.AnswerType   == "artist"){
                            quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(answer = it.get(0).author)
                        }
                        else if(quizUiState.question?.AnswerType   == "date"){
                            quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(answer = it.get(0).date)
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if (it != null) {
                        var answers = ArrayList<String>()
                        for(items in it){
                            answers.add(items.name)
                        }
                        answers.add(quizUiState.answer)
                        answers = answers.shuffled() as ArrayList<String>
                        quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(answerList = answers)
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        private fun getArtists(number: Int){
            repository.getArtists(number, onError = {}){
                if(number == 1) {   //////////////////////////////////////////////LEFT TO BE DONE
                    if (it != null) {
                        quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(subject = it.get(0).name)
                    }
                }else{
                    if (it != null) {
                        var answers = ArrayList<String>()
                        for(items in it){
                            answers.add(items.name)
                        }
                        answers.add(quizUiState.answer)
                        answers = answers.shuffled() as ArrayList<String>
                        quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(answerList = answers)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private fun getDates(number: Int){
            repository.getDates(number, onError = {}){
                if(number == 1) {   //////////////////////////////////////////////LEFT TO BE DONE
                    if (it != null) {
                        quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(subject = it.get(0).date)
                    }
                }else{
                    if (it != null) {
                        var answers = ArrayList<String>()
                        for(items in it){
                            answers.add(items.date)
                        }
                        answers.add(quizUiState.answer)
                        answers = answers.shuffled() as ArrayList<String>
                        quizUiState = quizUiState.copy(answerList = answers)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fun resetUi(){
            viewModelScope.launch {
                // do API call
                quizUiState = QuizUiState()
                loadQuestion()

            }
        }



}
        // get random question -> according to type ->
        // get random song/album -> set question answer according to Answer type
data class QuizUiState(
    val answerList: List<String>? = null,
    val question: Question? = null,
    val answer: String = "",
    val subject: String = "",

)
```

And this is the test:

```
package com.example.myfirstapplication.quiz

import androidx.compose.ui.test.*
import androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.createComposeRule
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith


@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class QuizScreenTest{

    @JvmField
    @Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    //create a test that checks questions are displayed and when the user clicks on an answer, the next question is displayed
    @Test
    fun testQuestionDisplayed(){
        val quizViewModel = QuizViewModel()
        val navToNextQuestion:(id:String,totalScore:String) -> Unit = {id,totalScore ->}
        val navToResult:(id:String,totalScore:String) -> Unit = {id,totalScore ->}
        val questionid: String = "1"
        val totalScore: String = "0"

        composeTestRule.setContent {
            QuizScreen(quizViewModel,navToNextQuestion,navToResult,questionid,totalScore)
        }

        //check that the question is displayed and click next
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Question 1").assertExists()
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Next").assertExists().performClick()

        //check that the next question is displayed
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Question 2").assertExists()



    }

}
```

When I run it it says:
java.lang.AssertionError: Failed: assertExists.

Thank you in advance